# Work Items, Pull Requests menu not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm using VSTS and Visual Studio enterprise on two different machines (both VS2015U3 on Win10). The project has a git-repository. On one machine I do have all expected menu's (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/work-team-explorer ) on the other some (pull requests, work items) are missing. On both machines editing code and commiting/synching works fine.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you check `[ ] Add to source control` when you create a new project?

Comment: The project IS in sourcecontrol (git on VSTS) and commiting, push, synch is working as expected. Only some menu's i.e. work items and pull requests are missing on one of my machines.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The reason is that you just connect to the local git repository and it likes this:
[image]

You configured Remotes (Home=>Settings=>Repository Settings=>Remotes), so you can commit and sync.

Refer to these steps to connect to the remote repository.

1. Go to Team Explorer
2. Click Manage connections=>Connect to Team project
   [image]
3. After that Open Solution in Solutions section (if it is empty, you need to clone this repository)
   [image]

Comment: Repo was already cloned. But clicking on 'connect' did it. Weird behavior.

Comment: Gah!  I guess I've just been asking the wrong questions of "teh google" for the last several months, because every search result had me doing this weird "clone the repo, then refresh the connection list, then restart VS" which never worked.  

This.  THIS right here finally worked.  FINALLY.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, you should check all of the below links are the same: 1. remote origin url in git config file under .git folder in your project folder 2. the url you declared in manage connections to connect 3. team explorer > settings > repository settings > git > fetch/push urls. If anyone of these are different, than connect doesn't work. I had problem at my company where we had 2 different urls directing to the same tfs server (like: http://oldurl:8080/tfs and https://newurl/tfs) and combining them ended up not letting us connect to remote like this.

Comment: This is **very** unintuitive. I think that if a `remote` is set, `Visual Studio` should automatically connect. Or, at least provide an indication that a connection is required.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. It was resolved by re-connecting to the tfs-server. on VS 2017 Team Explorer go to 'Manage Connections' and 'Add Server'.

Answer (score 5):

Steps using VS (Visual Studio) 2019:

1. Manage Connections > Connect to a Project...
2. Expand server, and project to find the repo you want, then
3. If it is already cloned, "Connect" should be the default option - click it!

And why Microsoft doesn't just auto-magically do this bewilders me!  I could sync and all, but no Pull-request until I jump through this little connect to the server/project/repo steps..

Comment: When I try to add a connection it only allows me to add an Azure DevOps Server.  I've upgraded to the most recent release of 2019 by the way.

Edit: turns out that's what they're calling TFS now.

Comment: Server/service list can have a mix of TFS/on-premise based service, and Azure DevOps (cloud based) service denoted with server/hardware stack, or cloud icon, respectively.  Expand these to either drill down into collections (TFS) or Projects (cloud).

Comment: Adam, are you referring to VS 2019?

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me after I upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to 15.6.2.  I was able to push my changed to the server, commit, sync, etc. but for some reason when I tried to make a Pull Request, that option was not listed in Team Explorer.  I searched and found this solution to help out.  Still  unsure why I could push/sync, but could not do a pull request since it said I was not connected to the TFS server.

Once I reconnected, the Pull Request option re-appeared and I could make my Pull Request.  Hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was not able to create a Pull Request from Visual Studio. This started happening when I changed my computer password. The solution is that you connect again with your project.

Answer (score 0):

En Tools - Options - Preview Features
Uncheck the option 'New git user experience'

Answer (score 0):

Just reconnect from Team Explorer again and you will be able to see all the options again.